# How can I show AVPlayerLayer as a fullscreen?

Tags: swift

a View Controller component is added in Main.storyboard window.

[image]

`View as: Iphone8` option is selected in Main.storyboard window

[image]

`TestViewController.swift` file is created and it is showed as a reference:

[image]

`UIView` component is added

[image]

constraints are added for the `UIView` component:

[image]

`UIView`'s background color is changed:

[image]

outlet is created for the `UIView`:

[image]

and then below codes are written in TestViewController.swift file

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

private var player: AVPlayer!
@IBOutlet weak var videoUiViewOutlet: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupView()
}

private func setupView()
{
    let path  = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clouds", ofType: "mp4")!)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: path)
    self.player = player
    let newLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    newLayer.frame = self.videoUiViewOutlet.frame
    self.videoUiViewOutlet.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
    newLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    player.play()

    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayer.ActionAtItemEnd.none

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.videoDidPlayToEnd(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"), object: player.currentItem)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteredBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteredForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func videoDidPlayToEnd(notification: Notification)
{
    let player: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    player.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
}

@objc func enteredBackground() {
    player.pause()
}

@objc func enteredForeground() {
    player.play()
}
}
```

and then app is run in Iphone 8 Plus. Here is the screen shot from Iphone 8 Plus:

[image]

**My question**: I would like to see video as a full screen for all devices. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please let me know if you can't see images that I have attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `frame`  inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` where correct `bounds` exists

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    newLayer.frame = self.videoUiViewOutlet.bounds 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having your `videoUiViewOutlet` as a plain UIView and manually create the `AVPlayerLayer` you can have a subclass that overrides `layerClass`:

```
class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

Using this you won't have to handle the frame.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlayer)

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try this

```
newLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
```

instead of

```
newLayer.frame = self.videoUiViewOutlet.frame
self.videoUiViewOutlet.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
```